# file is backwards, literally

Tags: python, reverse, elf

I have a file that I am looking at. When I open it in a hex editor, the start shows all 00 00 while the bottom shows 64 C4 54 F7. Magic bytes for an ELF is 7F 45 4C 46 which is the reverse of that. I am using python to try and flip the program back around, however when I do I get F7 54 C4 64 instead of the desired 7F 45 4C 46. Here is the code I am using

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Error: one argument is required!"
    exit(-1)

try:
    f1 = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
except IOError:
    print "Error: the file cannot be opened."
    exit(-1)

# else
lines = []
for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    reversedLine = line[::-1]
    lines.append(reversedLine)
f1.close()

reversedLines = lines[::-1]
for line in reversedLines:
    print line
```

[image: end of file]

[image: after script]

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you want to reverse it as a sequence of 4-bit chunks rather than a series of bytes. Where did this file come from, though? Why does it resemble an ELF file reversed as a sequence of 4-bit chunks?

Comment: I'm helping a friend, was told it was possibly an ELF. When I looked at it initially it just showed "data" with the file command so I doubted it was an ELF, tried a few other things...nothing. Then I opened it in hex and I saw the magic bytes. Mostly just sparked my curiosity.

Comment: If it's a binary file, I don't think `for line in f1` is the right way to read it.

Comment: actually i think your program is already working, or am I blind?
http://imgur.com/4iWXY62

Comment: most likely that is my issue John

Comment: KingMak, its working on the text. I need to change some things and see if I can get it to work with this binary file like John said. I didn't even think about that. http://imgur.com/a/1HeaC thats my result. Should be using    `with open('file','rb')

Comment: glad i helped you put the pieces together :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = []
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    ch = f.read(1)
    while ch != "":
        byte = ord(ch)
        reverse_byte = chr((byte & 15) << 4 | byte >> 4)
        l.insert(0, reverse_byte)
        ch = f.read(1)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'wb') as g:
    for byte in l:
        g.write(byte)
```

Comment: what is the b referring to in reverse_byte @JackYang? I see what you are doing with the bitwise but b isn't defined. referring to byte?

Comment: Yes, it should be byte. My typo.

Comment: hmm its not flipping anything. After running it on the file the only thing in there is 00 . All the other data has been erased. http://imgur.com/a/DqYFO

Comment: Sorry @digicode. Please try it again. I tested it and it's working.

Comment: I accepted the answer, I ended up getting it to work. It was an error on my end not with your code. Thanks very much :) @JackYang